# Spring 3 MVC access Global Variable from Controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have one public variable in Logincontroller.java, its setting Boolean flag = true for all JSP pages if there are some specific users.

I want to access this Global variable in Header.jsp, how can i do so without using ModelandView because if i use MV i have to change code for all @RequestMapping JSP pages ... I am new to Spring Framework thanks...

```
public Boolean flag = false;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView error(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) { 
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(); 
    ............... 
    if(flag){ // want to avoid doing this for each pages 
        mv.addObject("specialUser", true); // want to avoid doing this for each pages 
    } 
    return mv 
}
```

same way i have multiple @RequestMapping for different pages like /admin, /user, /index ,etc

Comment: There is no such thing as a Global variable in Java. What do you actually mean?

Comment: Sorry i meant public variable for Logincontroller.java

Comment: Post  your `@Controller` code.

Comment: 'public Boolean flag = false;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView error(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
...............
return mv
}'

same way i have multiple @RequestMapping for different pages like /admin, /user, /index ,etc

Comment: Code always looks bad in comments. Edit your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I think I have the solution, although I haven't tried it out yet.

I think what we a [ViewPreparer](http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/advanced/preparer.html).  They seem pretty straight forward.

Good luck!

Huw